# UITableView cells overlap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, bluetooth-lowenergy

Im running into issues with my ConnectionViewController that I am trying to implement. It lists BLE devices just not properly within the row, cells are overlapping and there are two headers. I believe the is due to the way setup the table in `configuringTableView` as i am adding a subview inside a tableViewController.

ConnectionViewController.h

```
@interface ConnectDeviceViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDataSource,CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate >{
    NSMutableArray* cbArray;
}

    @property ( strong ,nonatomic) UITableView *mainTableView;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) CBCentralManager* centralManager;
@end
```

ConnectionViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self configureTableView];
    self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];  
}
- (void)configureTableView
{
    cbArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    _mainTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT-20) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _mainTableView.delegate = self;
    _mainTableView.dataSource = self;
    _mainTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _mainTableView.backgroundView = nil;
    _mainTableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO;
    _mainTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    [self.view addSubview:_mainTableView];
}     

-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral*)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    CBPeripheral* currentPer = peripheral;
    if(![cbArray containsObject:currentPer]){
        [cbArray addObject:currentPer];
    }

    [_possibleAdapters addObject:peripheral], peripheral.delegate = self;
    [_mainTableView reloadData];


///Stop trying to connect to every peripheral, discover then connecct.
//[_manager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:
(NSInteger)section
{

    return cbArray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"BLE_DEVICES";
    UITableViewCell* cell;
    cell = [self.mainTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier ];

      if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  }

      cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
      cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault;

      CBPeripheral* currentPer = [cbArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      cell.textLabel.text = (currentPer.name ? currentPer.name : @"Not available");

      return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   [_mainTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total count %lu",(unsigned long)cbArray.count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 40;
}

#pragma mark UITableView Datasource

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 50;
}
```

I'm not attempting to connect to it yet, im just tyring to scan for devices and list them on the table dynamically as theyre found.

[image: This is how my tableview looks]

Comment: Please properly indent your code, it looks unreadable.

Comment: UITableViewCell* cell;
    cell = [self.mainTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier ];
 instead of you can use like this  UITableViewCell. *cell = [tableView
 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

Comment: @3rdeye7 add this line cell.clipsToBounds = YES;

Comment: What do you see if you *don't* add the tableview in viewDidLoad; it looks like you have another tablview or some thing in your base view controller.

Comment: @3rdeye7 can you debug your view Hierarchy? it seems to me there are two UITableViews

Comment: @Paulw11 I was thinking the same thing. First i cant see my tableview in the reference outlets, yeah the delegate and datasource are set but i cant set my tableview property to tableview. I think this is actually a problem with my xcode and storyboard, as story board is not letting me assign the appropriate custom class.

Comment: @Paulw11 My story board isnt listing my viewcontroller classes in the drop down either. Not to sure what to do about this

Answer (score 0):

Add this delegate method

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return 50; // change what you want
}
```

**For section**

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 40;
}
```

Comment: Nope, this just just adjusts the cells size. Does not fix the overlap problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use below code in cellForRowAtIndexPath after allocating cell and before adding subviews.

```
for (id object in cell.contentView.subviews)
{
[object removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `autolayout` issue and because of that it is overlapping the cells. But you can try setting `autolayout` properly on your attributes inside cell(pinned leading, trailing, top and bottom). And after that use the `automaticdimesion` to set the height of row and header in your `viewdidload` method like below.

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0; 
self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 40
self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Note:- While using the automatic dimesion then there is no need to implement `tableView` `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and `header and footer` height `delegate` method.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I've got it to work. It isn't a tablecell issue, its the actually view controller. Instead of using a UITableViewController I used a UIViewController. What I think was happening is calling `[self.view addSubview:_mainTableView];` in my configureTableView is continuously adding the tableview over my initial tableviewcontroller.

Another issue was `numberOfSectionsInTableView` I removed this delegate method.

ConnectDeviceViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>

@interface ConnectDeviceViewController : UIViewController <CBCentralManagerDelegate >

@property(nonatomic,strong) CBCentralManager* centralManager;


@end
```

ConnectDeviceViewController.m

```
#import "ConnectDeviceViewController.h"


#define SCREEN_WIDTH [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height


@interface ConnectDeviceViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
    UITableView* tableView;
    NSMutableArray* cbArray;

 }

 @end

@implementation ConnectDeviceViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //tableView.delegate = self;
    //tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self configureTableView];
    self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];


    //cbArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
- (void)configureTableView
{
    cbArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT-20) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    tableView.backgroundView = nil;
    tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO;
    tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark <CBCentralManagerDelegate>
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{
    switch (central.state) {
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff:
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off");
        break;
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready");
        [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
        break;
    case CBCentralManagerStateResetting:
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is resetting");
        break;
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized:
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized");
        break;
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnknown:
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown");
        break;
    case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported:
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}

-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral*)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI{
    CBPeripheral* currentPer = peripheral;
    if(![cbArray containsObject:currentPer]){
       [cbArray addObject:currentPer];
    }
   LOG( @"DISCOVER %@ (RSSI=%@) w/ advertisement %@", peripheral, RSSI, advertisementData );


 [tableView reloadData];


///Stop trying to connect to every peripheral, then connecct.
//[_manager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
}


- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {

    NSLog(@"Connection successfull to peripheral: %@",peripheral);

    //Do somenthing after successfull connection.
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didFailToConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Connection failed to peripheral: %@",peripheral);

    //Do something when a connection to a peripheral failes.
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark <UITableViewDelegate>

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return cbArray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"BLE_DEVICES";
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    cell = [self->tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier ];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.clipsToBounds = YES;

    CBPeripheral* currentPer = [cbArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = (currentPer.name ? currentPer.name : @"Not available");

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   [self->tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    CBPeripheral* currentPer = [cbArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:currentPer options:nil];
    [_bdAdapter connect];
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total count %lu",(unsigned long)cbArray.count];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return 50; // change what you want
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 40; 
}
@end
```

This works correctly. If anyone has the solution using a tableviewcontroller please share.